# Arbitrary file syntax in WebStorm 7

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to set syntax for currently opened file to any arbitrary type? The way you can do it in Sublime? Or the syntax highlighting always determined based on the file extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible. Please see [IDEA-103297](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103297). The highlighting is based on extensions indeed - or, more exactly, on the patterns specified for each file type in Settings/File types.